# UIButton not clickable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I've searched in other posts but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a UIButton that is not being possible to click. When I click, it doesn't darken. 
The problem is not about the selector method.

Can someone help me?! Here's the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 436)];

    UIView *detailsView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// I have other components here and after the UIButton

    UIButton *btnOpenPDF = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnOpenPDF setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnVisualizarPdf"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btnOpenPDF setFrame:CGRectMake(35, totalHeight, 249, 30)];
    btnOpenPDF.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [btnOpenPDF addTarget:self action:@selector(openPdf:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [detailsView addSubview:btnOpenPDF];

    [scroll addSubview:detailsView];

    [self addSubview:scroll];

}
```

The code above is inside an UIView which is called through an UIViewController through the method -loadView().

Below is the method openPdf:

```
- (IBAction)openPdf:(id)sender{
// Creates an instance of a UIWebView
    UIWebView *aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,450)];

// Sets the scale of web content the first time it is displayed in a web view
    aWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    [aWebView setDelegate:self];

//Create a URL object.
    NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://portalarp.com.br/portal/%@",[[[[[[[delegateFunctions products] objectAtIndex:[delegateFunctions selectedProductIndex]] objectForKey:@"ata"] objectForKey:@"nm_arquivo"] objectForKey:@"text"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""]]];

//URL Requst Object
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

//load the URL into the web view.
    [aWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    [self addSubview:aWebView];
    [aWebView release];
}
```

Comment: are you sure about the event "UIControlEventTouchDown" .. or you try to press as usual "UIControlEventTouchUpInside" ??

Comment: It is using the UIControlEventTouchDown because I've seen in another post that it worked for someone... however, using both of them, it still doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by "still doesn't work" .. the button is not highlighted or the selector is not calling at all ?!

Comment: The button is not highlighted, so the selector is not being called at all...

Comment: ok try to change the detailView backGround color to red and check that your button is **completely** inside the red area.

Comment: I've just done this and the button is inside the view... I can't really figure out why it's not working. I've already set up userInteractionEnabled to YES and nothing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is the scrollView .. is not forwarding the touch event .. try to do the following :

```
scroll.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
scroll.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

Comment: did you try to add the button directly on scrollView without add it in a view ?

Answer (score 7):

`drawRect` is an odd place to put this code.  It's called to draw the view, and could conceivably be called a lot -- you shouldn't be building the view there.  For example, `drawRect` might be called when you touch the button (to redraw it)

If this is in a UIView, probably the `init` is a much better place to put this code.

Comment: Even putting the code at the init method, the button is still not clickable.

Comment: does anything happen? Crash, exception, etc?  Show the declaration for `openPdf:`

Comment: Also, you took all view building code out of drawRect, right?  Is there anything left in drawRect?  Probably shouldn't be unless you need a custom view that isn't a composition of built-in ones.

Comment: Nothing happens! It's like if there is some invisible component over the button. The openPdf: is not ever called!

I took everything out of drawRect method as you said! I edited the post with the openPdf method.

Comment: Try just making a simple view with one button -- does that work?